# why I do not have video infomation with this url

Tags: gdata-api, youtube.net-api

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/DC4048825BC38BD7?v=2&start-index=3&max-results=1
I don't have the video infomation with this url

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I see in that XML is the feed/media:group/media:content element, which references http://www.youtube.com/p/DC4048825BC38BD7, which is the desired(?) flash video.